# Symfony 5.1 caracteres extraños

Tags: reactjs, symfony

Tengo una aplicacion symfony 5.1 con React y API platform.

El problema es que cada vez que hago una peticion a la API o cada vez que el symfony renderiza un HTML, al principio de cada html o respuesta json que saca hay una serie de caracteres extraños que manda y no se porque.

los caracteres siempre estan el la primera linea y es una cadena larga, parece un rombo con un signo de interogacion dentro.

al recibir el json dañado, el javascript no reconoce el array y da error.

ejemplo de funcion que devuelve una respuesta:

```
/**
 * @Route("/myorders", name="app_my_orders")
 * @param SerializerInterface $serializer
 * @return Response
 */
public function myOrders( SerializerInterface $serializer):?Response
{


    $result = $this->shoppingCartService->getMyOrders($this->getUser());
    if (($result)) {
        return new Response($serializer->serialize($result, 'json'), 200);
    }
    if (!($result)) {
        return new Response(null, 204);
    }

}
```

a esta funcion le paso el objecto de usuario y me devuelve las orders en un json, o me devuelve 204 si el usuario no esta login.

```
^ Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response {#3199 ▼
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag {#3289 ▼
    #computedCacheControl: array:2 [▶]
    #cookies: []
    #headerNames: array:4 [▶]
    #headers: array:4 [▶]
    #cacheControl: []
  }
  #content: """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    
            <title>
```

lo que se ve arriba es un dump del objecto response donde se ha renderizado.
aqui los caracteres no salen.
de echo no he podido ni hacer copy/paste de esos caracteres.

como puedo ver o corregir este fallo?
gracias

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: no funciona el edit

Comment: Si no te funciona el enlace de editar, siempre puedes eliminar la pregunta, ya que eres tú el creador, y volver a formularla con más detalles. Así será mejor recibida y es más fácil, que encuentres la ayuda apropiada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado.

Hay que quitar las siguientes lineas de composer.json

```
    "api-platform/core": "^2.5",
```

después

```
composer update
```

después

```
composer require api
```